# how to fix tablecontent based upon heading levels? style

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I'm working on a document whose table of contents needs fixed.

```
        Heading 1 starts at 17 font 
        Heading 2 starts at 16 font
```

But in toc it display as :-

1. Test heading 17
2. *TEST* heading 16

Instead it should look like this

1. Test heading 17

   2. *TEST* heading 16

Kindly help.

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly applied the appropriate styles to each heading? i.e Heading 1 and Heading 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on create new TOC, rest see picture

[image]